# Incompatible types issue when compiling - void to MimeMessage

Tags: java, variables

I have encountered an issue while compiling my app, the error is:
`incompatible types: void cannot be converted to javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`

It occurs in this part of the code:

```
getEmailService().parseEmail(parseEmailRequest.getFileName(), parseEmailRequest.getFileContent());
```

and the methods are as follows:

```
private EmailService getEmailService() {
return new EmailService();
}
```

and

```
public MimeMessage parseEmail(String fileName, Part fileContent) {
        return getParseEmailUseCase()
                .withEmailFileStorage(getEmailFileStorage())
                .withFilePathBuilder(getFilePathBuilder())
                .withEmailParser(getEmailParser())
                .withFileName(fileName)
                .withFileContent(fileContent)
                .run();
    }
```

This is strange to be because I wanted it as a variable `message`

```
private void setEmailMessage(ParseEmailRequest parseEmailRequest) {
    message = getEmailService()
            .parseEmail(parseEmailRequest.getFileName(), parseEmailRequest.getFileContent());
}
```

`message` is a field

```
private MimeMessage message;
```

and this is when I get error and when I remove `message` and keep only:

```
getEmailService().parseEmail(parseEmailRequest.getFileName(), parseEmailRequest.getFileContent());
```

program is compiled. What is more, when I use my IDE (intellij) for assigning a variable to above code, `MimeMessage` is automatically selected so it means `getEmailService().parseEmail(parseEmailRequest.getFileName(), parseEmailRequest.getFileContent());` returns `MimeMessage` as I wanted.

All of the above is happning in class `EmailHandler`.

I don't understand where the `void` comes from in the error message since my methods return specified types. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`getEmailService().(parseEmailRequest.getFileName(), parseEmailRequest.getFileContent());`

should be:

`getEmailService().parseEmail(parseEmailRequest.getFileName(), parseEmailRequest.getFileContent());`

You didn't provide much context to your code, but from what I assume, you intend to create the `message` object within `EmailService`. `getEmailService()` returns you an instance to the object `EmailService` which then lets you call the `parseEmail()` method. Note that if `EmailService` is intended as a factory class of some sort, other classes won't be able to use its methods if they are using the publicity modifier `private`.

Comment: yes, sorry. must have removed it by mistake when editing the post :(

Comment: oh, ok. to clarify - all this is in handler. getEmailService() is a private method in handler and the rest is in one of the methods.

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake. I got the modifiers swapped around. Yeah, other than the typo, your code's fine.

Comment: Wait, so you get the same error even with the correct `parseEmail` stuff? What are you calling the method from?

Comment: exactly! I call it in the Handler in a private method, let me add it to the post